# Need help designing database, Create a table with additional columns/fields in the table, or create a new table for each different type?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, eav

So the tables that I have are Certificates, Approvers, CertificatesApprovers, Categories, Approvees, Status, AdditionalFields, AdditionalFieldsValues.

Many Certificates to Many Approvers relationship.

1 Category to Many Certificates relationship.

1 Category to Many AdditionalFields relationship

1 AdditionalFields to Many AdditionalFieldsValues relationship

If there are different types of Certificates which will have different fields/columns, should I create a different unique table for each type of Certificate or just add the additional fields/columns in the Certificates table (but some of the entries will be blank)?

For example, a MedicalCertificate will have a field Specialization whereas a DrillCertificate will have a field DrillType.

Certificates Table

| ID | CategoryID | ApproveeID | ValidFrom | ValidUntil | StatusID | Specialization | DrillType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 1/4/2021 | 2/4/2021 | 1 | Oncology |  |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 1/4/2021 | 2/4/2021 | 1 |  | Traditional |

OR

MedicalCertificates Table

| ID | ApproveeID | ValidFrom | ValidUntil | StatusID | Specialization |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1/4/2021 | 2/4/2021 | 1 | Oncology |
| 2 | 5 | 1/4/2021 | 2/4/2021 | 1 | Haemotology |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm more of a fan of your second option because it's more normalized than the first option, but even better for normalization would be to have one `Certificates` table with the common fields in it `ID`, `ApproveeID`, `ValidFrom`, `ValidUntil`, `StatusID` and then a generic auxillary table to store the uncommon fields in.

For example, the auxillary table could be called `CertificatesAdditionalInfo` with fields like `ID`, `CertifcateID`, `Info1Name`, `Info1Value`, `Info2Name`, `Info2Value`, etc. The info fields would be nullable so that they're flexible.

Implementing it this way means you only need one table for the main data for `Certifcates`, which will lead to less data duplication, better long term maintainability, and likely improved performance. Also please pick better table and column names (though the column names should be generic) than me, as I suck at naming things.

Answer (score 0):

1:many -- Just an id in one of the tables to link to the other.

many:many -- Need a table to link them.  It will have (probably) exactly 2 columns, namely the two ids.

key-value pairs -- read about EAV and its evils and benefits.